# How to get fullcalendar to work with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get fullcalendar on a phonegap app. My code is working on a browser but on the android emulador it is just not showing the calendar.
I also tried to get it inside 'device ready' but if I do that I get Object [object Object] has no method 'fullCalendar' error.

inside device ready:

```
var app = {

        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents()
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false)
            $(document).on("pageshow", app.onDeviceReady);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready')
        },

        receivedEvent: function(id){

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/'
                    }
                ]
            });
   }
```

if i put it outside it will run fine on browser.. but not on emulator :/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KrZJr/86/

Is it possible to use fullcalendar on android or is it a plugin with the same effect that works on android?

Answer (score 0):

found an example that works on phonegap. http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ZSd2C/

had to use pageshow event

```
 $(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data)
```